# How can I write a more general (but efficient) version of attoparsec's takeWhile1?

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, attoparsec

`Data.Attoparsec.Text` exports `takeWhile` and `takeWhile1`:

> ```hs
> takeWhile :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Text
> ```
>
> Consume input as long as the predicate returns `True`, and return the consumed input.
>
> This parser does not fail. It will return an empty string if the predicate returns `False` on the first character of input.
>
> [...]
>
> ```hs
> takeWhile1 :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Text
> ```
>
> Consume input as long as the predicate returns `True`, and return the consumed input.
>
> This parser requires the predicate to succeed on at least one character of input: it will fail if the predicate never returns `True` or if there is no input left.

`attoparsec`'s documentation encourages the user to

> Use the `Text`-oriented parsers whenever possible, e.g. `takeWhile1` instead of `many1 anyChar`. There is about a factor of 100 difference in performance between the two kinds of parser.

Those two parsers are very useful, but I keep feeling the need for a more general version of `takeWhile1`, more specifically, some hypothetical parser

```hs
takeWhileLo :: (Char -> Bool) -> Int -> Parser Text
takeWhileLo f lo = undefined
```

that would parse *at least* `lo` characters satisfying predicate `f`, where `lo` is an arbitrary nonnegative integer.

I had a look at [`takeWhile1`'s implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.2.0/docs/src/Data-Attoparsec-Text-Internal.html#takeWhile1), but it uses a bunch of functions private to `Data.Attoparsec.Text.Internal` and doesn't seem easily generalizable.

I came up with the following applicative implementation:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Prelude                  hiding ( takeWhile )

import           Control.Applicative             ( (<*>) )
import           Data.Text                       ( Text )
import qualified Data.Text           as T

import           Data.Attoparsec.Text

takeWhileLo :: (Char -> Bool) -> Int -> Parser Text
takeWhileLo f lo =
  T.append . T.pack <$> count lo (satisfy f) <*> takeWhile f
```

It works as advertised,

```hs
λ> parseOnly (takeWhileLo (== 'a') 4) "aaa"
Left "not enough input"
λ> parseOnly (takeWhileLo (== 'a') 4) "aaaa"
Right "aaaa"
λ> parseOnly (takeWhileLo (== 'a') 4) "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Right "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

but the need for packing the intermediate list of results returned by `count` worries me, especially for cases where `lo` is large... It seems to go against the recommendation to

> use the `Text`-oriented parsers whenever possible [...]

Am I missing something? Is there a more efficient/idiomatic way of implementing such a `takeWhileLo` combinator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Parser` is a monad, so you can just inspect the return value and fail if the length's not right:

```
takeWhileLo :: (Char -> Bool) -> Int -> Parser Text
takeWhileLo f lo = do
  text <- takeWhile f
  case T.compareLength text lo of
    LT -> empty
    _  -> return text
```

`compareLength` is from the `text` package. It's more efficient than comparing `text`'s length, because `compareLength` may short-circuit.

Comment: I guess I was too focused on implementing `takeWhileLo` as an applicative combinator. Your suggestion makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `mempty` instead of `empty`?

Comment: That also works. We have `Monoid`, `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` instances for `Parser`, and `mempty`, `empty` and `mzero` all express failure.